# how to get the currentUserInfo from _User class in Parse using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I tried this:

```
var data:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

func loadData() {
    var userQuery = PFUser.query()!
    userQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
    userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
       if let objects = objects {
          for object in objects  {
              self.data.addObject(object)
          }
       }
    }
    println(data) // this gives an empty NSMutableArray.
}
```

Is there any other way to get the data of current user? , I am doing this to make the profile Screen of the current user..Thanks for your time..

Comment: Instead of the for loop you can use `self.data.addObjectsFromArray(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to access the current user

```
if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
    PFUser.currentUser()!.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ (user: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            var u = user as! PFUser
            //Access the fetched user HERE
         }
    })
    //NOT here, it will be nil here
}
```

Comment: And data will always be empty there, you are getting the data asynchronously, you need to use the data within the completion block

Comment: thanks. i got the user data but if i use this `UserNameLabel.text = self.data["fullName"] as String` then i get the error: cannot assign a value of type 'String' to a value of type 'String?' . i want to show the 'fullName' of the current user in a label in my app , the 'fullName' is in `data` NSMutableArray. Sorry to bother you, but i am not able to do so..

Comment: UserNameLabel.text = self.data["fullName"] as! String

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87090/discussion-between-akshay-kheveria-and-swinny89).